# Ruby on rails one model created as much i want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, scaffolding

I want to be able to put a number in the form section and that amount of models will be created.

I want to create a page with players. i want the option to submit for example 50 players. And  on the second page will be 50 text area's where i can submit the names of each player.

I tried scaffolding but it did not work.

I couls not find a topic about this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any validation on your Player model?

Comment: I am very new to ruby, do you mean validation that players have to validate if they are real with email etc. Then no. There is no validation. I only want to add a name and if has to preview it on a page

Comment: I meant ActiveRecord validations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: instead of doing this, try watching http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.  it's a very old video but should be a better approach overall.

Comment: Yes i do have validation on my player model, and i watched the video and i will do nested models. But i did not know how to make multiple same models. I did find a topic about it yesterday but i could not unserstand it, couse my lack of coding. I will have to learn a lot more

Answer (score 0):

Your problem requires something a little more custom than scaffolding.
You will most likely need to create a few actions on your controller:

- One to render the view where you will pick the number of models **[GET]**
- One to submit the number of models you want to create and to render the form with 50 fields **[POST]**
- One to submit the new models **[POST]**

Basically, you will have one field on the first view to select the number of new models you are trying to create and based on that you will render the next view with as many fields as that first number you picked.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you i will try it, and write my coding here. Hope it works